# How to quickcheck applicative homomorphism property?

Tags: haskell, applicative, quickcheck

As an exercise, I am trying to quickCheck the applicative's homomorphism property:

> pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)

When I try to write the property in a general way using phantom types, I seem to run into endless 'Could not deduce' errors. At this point I have added many type annotations to my code, and still am getting these errors.

My code is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Test.QuickCheck (quickCheck)
import Test.QuickCheck.Function (Fun, apply)

-- | phantom type
data T a = T

-- | pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)
prop_homomorphism :: (Applicative f, Eq b, Eq (f b)) => (T a) -> (T (f b)) -> Fun a b -> a -> Bool
prop_homomorphism T T (apply -> g) x = (pure (g :: a -> b) <*> pure x :: (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b) == (pure (g x) :: (A
pplicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)


prop_maybeint :: IO ()
prop_maybeint = do
  quickCheck (prop_homomorphism (T :: T Int) (T :: T (Maybe Int)))


main = do
  prop_maybeint
```

And the errors this gives are:

```
applicativehomomorphism.hs:11:40: error:
    • Could not deduce (Eq (f0 b0)) arising from a use of ‘==’
      from the context: (Applicative f, Eq b, Eq (f b))
        bound by the type signature for:
                   prop_homomorphism :: (Applicative f, Eq b, Eq (f b)) =>
                                        T a -> T (f b) -> Fun a b -> a -> Bool
        at applicativehomomorphism.hs:10:1-98
      The type variables ‘f0’, ‘b0’ are ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
        instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (a, b) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
        instance (Eq a, Eq b, Eq c) => Eq (a, b, c)
          -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
        ...plus 13 others
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression:
        (pure (g :: a -> b) <*> pure x :: (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)
        == (pure (g x) :: (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)
      In an equation for ‘prop_homomorphism’:
          prop_homomorphism T T (apply -> g) x
            = (pure (g :: a -> b) <*> pure x ::
                 (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)
              == (pure (g x) :: (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)

applicativehomomorphism.hs:11:41: error:
    • Could not deduce (Applicative f0)
        arising from an expression type signature
      from the context: (Applicative f, Eq b, Eq (f b))
        bound by the type signature for:
                   prop_homomorphism :: (Applicative f, Eq b, Eq (f b)) =>
                                        T a -> T (f b) -> Fun a b -> a -> Bool
        at applicativehomomorphism.hs:10:1-98
      The type variable ‘f0’ is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Applicative IO -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
        instance Applicative Maybe -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
        instance Applicative ((->) a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
        ...plus two others
        ...plus two instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely
        ‘(pure (g :: a -> b) <*> pure x ::
            (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)’
      In the expression:
        (pure (g :: a -> b) <*> pure x :: (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)
        == (pure (g x) :: (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)
      In an equation for ‘prop_homomorphism’:
          prop_homomorphism T T (apply -> g) x
            = (pure (g :: a -> b) <*> pure x ::
                 (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)
              == (pure (g x) :: (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)

applicativehomomorphism.hs:11:47: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘b2’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          prop_homomorphism :: forall (f :: * -> *) b a.
                               (Applicative f, Eq b, Eq (f b)) =>
                               T a -> T (f b) -> Fun a b -> a -> Bool
        at applicativehomomorphism.hs:10:22
      ‘b2’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        an expression type signature:
          forall a1 b2. a1 -> b2
        at applicativehomomorphism.hs:11:52
      Expected type: a1 -> b2
        Actual type: a -> b
    • In the first argument of ‘pure’, namely ‘(g :: a -> b)’
      In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘pure (g :: a -> b)’
      In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely
        ‘(pure (g :: a -> b) <*> pure x ::
            (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        g :: a -> b (bound at applicativehomomorphism.hs:11:33)
        prop_homomorphism :: T a -> T (f b) -> Fun a b -> a -> Bool
          (bound at applicativehomomorphism.hs:11:1)

applicativehomomorphism.hs:11:112: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘b1’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          prop_homomorphism :: forall (f :: * -> *) b a.
                               (Applicative f, Eq b, Eq (f b)) =>
                               T a -> T (f b) -> Fun a b -> a -> Bool
        at applicativehomomorphism.hs:10:22
      ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        an expression type signature:
          forall (f1 :: * -> *) b1. (Applicative f1, Eq (f1 b1)) => f1 b1
        at applicativehomomorphism.hs:11:126
      Expected type: f1 b1
        Actual type: f1 b
    • In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely
        ‘(pure (g x) :: (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)’
      In the expression:
        (pure (g :: a -> b) <*> pure x :: (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)
        == (pure (g x) :: (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)
      In an equation for ‘prop_homomorphism’:
          prop_homomorphism T T (apply -> g) x
            = (pure (g :: a -> b) <*> pure x ::
                 (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)
              == (pure (g x) :: (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => f b)
    • Relevant bindings include
        g :: a -> b (bound at applicativehomomorphism.hs:11:33)
        prop_homomorphism :: T a -> T (f b) -> Fun a b -> a -> Bool
          (bound at applicativehomomorphism.hs:11:1)
```

I've been fighting with this for a while and am pretty stuck. What is my problem?

Comment: Try enabling `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` and then `forall`-quantifying any type variables in the signature that you mention in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

luqui's suggestion solved this for me.

The problem was I needed to use `ScopedTypeVariables` and  `forall` in order to refer to type parameters outside their type signature in the function body's type annotations.

Some relevant resources on `ScopedTypeVariables` I came across:

- [24 Days of GHC Extensions: Scoped Type Variables](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-20-scoped-type-variables.html)
- [Haskell wiki: Scoped type variables](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables)
- [Wikibooks: Haskell/Existentially
  quantified types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types#The_forall_keyword)