# Quickcheck Applicative homomorphism law for Binary Tree

Tags: haskell, applicative, quickcheck

I am aware that the following question exists:

[haskell - How to quickcheck applicative homomorphism property? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257225/how-to-quickcheck-applicative-homomorphism-property)

However, the introduction of the following PRAGMA

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

didn't solve my issue.

These are my definitions:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Laws where

import Control.Applicative ((<$>), liftA3)

import Data.Monoid

import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Function
import Test.QuickCheck.Gen

data BinTree a = Empty | Node a (BinTree a) (BinTree a) deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Functor BinTree where
    fmap _ Empty = Empty
    fmap f (Node x hi hd) = Node (f x) (fmap f hi) (fmap f hd)

instance Applicative BinTree where
    -- pure :: a -> BinTree a
    pure x = Node x (pure x) (pure x)

    -- <*> :: BinTree (a -> b) -> BinTree a -> BinTree b
    _ <*> Empty = Empty -- L1, 
    Empty <*> t = Empty
    (Node f l r) <*> (Node x l' r') = Node (f x) (l <*> l') (r <*> r')

instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (BinTree a) where
    arbitrary = oneof [return Empty, -- oneof :: [Gen a] -> Gen a
                liftA3 Node arbitrary arbitrary arbitrary]
                
-- Identity
apIdentityProp :: (Applicative f, Eq (f a)) => f a -> Bool
apIdentityProp v = (pure id <*> v) == v

-- pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)   -- Homomorphism
apHomomorphismProp :: forall f a b. (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => Fun a b -> a -> Bool
apHomomorphismProp (apply -> g) x = (((pure g :: f (a -> b)) <*> (pure x :: f a)) :: f b) == (pure (g x) :: f b)

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck (apHomomorphismProp :: Fun Int Int -> Int -> Bool)
```

How can I fix the following error ?

> Could not deduce **(Applicative f0)**
> from the context: **(Applicative f, Eq (f b))**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been easier to analyse the problem if you had included the full error message, which mentions an *ambiguous type variable*. The thing that GHC is complaining about is that `f` does not appear anywhere in the type signature of `apHomomorphismProp`, except in the quantifier and constraints.

Why is that a problem? Well, it *isn't* a problem... but it used to be in older Haskell versions, because there was no way for the compiler to tell when you're *using* `apHomomorphismProp` what applicative it's supposed to test here. In fact this is still the case with the way you are using it: `apHomomorphismProp :: Fun Int Int -> Int -> Bool` does not mention `BinTree` in any way, so how is the compiler supposed to know that's what you mean? For all it knows, you could as well be asking for, say, the `Maybe` applicative to be tested here.

The solution, in modern Haskell, is `-XTypeApplications`, which just lets you explicitly say what a type variable should be instantiated with.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

main = quickCheck (apHomomorphismProp @BinTree :: Fun Int Int -> Int -> Bool)
```

In fact I would recommend also using this syntax to clarify the `Int` types:

```
main = quickCheck $ apHomomorphismProp @BinTree @Int @Int
```

However, there was still the compiler error with `apHomomorphismProp`, which is all because prior to `TypeApplications`, a signature like the one you gave to `apHomomorphismProp` was useless. But this restriction is now obsolete<sup>†</sup>, and it can be disabled with `-XAllowAmbiguousTypes`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax, AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}

apHomomorphismProp :: ∀ f a b. (Applicative f, Eq (f b)) => Fun a b -> a -> Bool
apHomomorphismProp (apply -> g) x = (pure @f g <*> pure x) == pure (g x)
```

Note that I only need to mention `@f` for one of the `pure`s, the other ones are automatically constrained to the same applicative.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>It's arguable whether it's really *obsolete*. What's probably still true is that if a beginner gives their function an ambiguous type, it's more likely a mistake that should be caught right there and then, rather than something that's actually intended for use with `-XTypeApplications`. An unintentionally ambiguous type can cause quite confusing errors further down the line.</sub>

Comment: Spectacular answer, thank you.

Comment: In this line: `apHomomorphismProp @BinTree :: Fun Int Int -> Int -> Bool`. How does `@BinTree` works ? The first type prefixed with `@` corresponds to the first  type variable appearing here: `∀ f a b` ?

Comment: And could you please clarify why this type signature `apHomomorphismProp :: Fun Int Int -> Int -> Bool` was useless ? Is that because I do not mention the quantified type variable in the type signature ?

Comment: `(==)` is infix 4 and `<*>` is infixl 4. Don't you need parenthesis on your last equation ?

Comment: Yes, the first variable behind the `∀` is the first one to be filled in by the type application. The full type annotation on the use of `apHomomorphism` is just unnecessary and repetitive – all that's needed is to pin down the two `Int` arguments, and that's again easiest done as type applications to `apHomomorphism`.

Comment: Thank you ! Understood. When I run `quickCheck $ apHomomorphismProp @BinTree @Int @Int`, I get `(0 tests)`. Could you tell me whether the function runs on your side ? I am not managing to make it successfully test that Applicative law.

Comment: Hmmthat's strange, but this seems to be unrelated to your original question, so you should perhaps ask a new one about it.

Comment: I’ll ask a new one, then. Thanks for the reply !